# Apply calculation across a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below table,

```
ID Emp_Name  Type
1  JDoe      Except 
1  JDoe      NTF
1  JDoe      JD
1  JDoe      NULL
2  Kevin     NTF
2  Kevin     FTP
3  Rob       NTF
```

I'm trying to create an additional column which assigns a value '1' to all the emp rows which has an "Except" type

Below is my expected output,

```
ID Emp_Name  Type    Calc
1  JDoe      Except  1
1  JDoe      NTF     1
1  JDoe      JD      1
1  JDoe      NULL    1
2  Kevin     NTF     0
2  Kevin     FTP     0
3  Rob       NTF     0
```

I'm in search of ideas for this to be done using apply operator (I've tried few queries using sub queries but it isn't performing well so I'm looking for a different approach).

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest looking at `CASE` and a `COUNT` window function if you haven't tried anything. Then, if you fail, post your attempt(s) and explain why they didn't work.

Comment: yes perfect, `MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'EXCEPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER( PARTITION BY Emp_Name) AS [Exception]` did the job... not sure why I dint think about it before

Comment: What makes you think that apply would perform better than subqueries? See [Using Apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply)

Answer (score 1):

Try using CASE, see example below.

```
Select id, emp_name, type,
case
        when type = 'Except' then 1
        else 0
end as calc
from
table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below way - using window function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04965f0e6dadea99150e13f04670ff13)**

```
select *,
      count(case when types='Except' then 1 end) over(partition by emp_name order by id) as calc
from tablename
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  emp_name    types   calc
1   JDoe        Except  1
1   JDoe        NTF     1
1   JDoe        JD      1
1   JDoe                1
2   Kevin       NTF     0
2   Kevin       FTP     0
3   Rob         NTF     0
```

Answer (score 0):

First You have to add a Column

```
ALTER TABLE #Temp   //YourTableName
ADD Calc INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
```

Then use Update Query....

```
UPDATE  #Temp
SET     Calc = 1
WHERE ID IN 
(
    SELECT ID FROM #Temp  WHERE [TYPE]='Except' 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function.  Because you want just `0` or `1`, I would recommend `max()`:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when type = 'Except' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by type) as calc
from t;
```

If `calc` were actually a column in the table and you want to populate it, use `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when type = 'Except' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by type) as new_calc
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set calc = new_calc;
```